# Как динамически менять текст элемента?

Tags: javascript

Для примера возьмем простую кнопку:

```
<button>imgname.jpeg</button>
```

Задача состоит в следующем:
При клике на нее, прям в ней можно редактировать название, можно стирать/вписывать любой текст(как в поле input), при этом расширение(все что после точки), трогать нельзя.

Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: [contenteditable](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/contenteditable)

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/ExVLabb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить - необходимо дважды кликнуть по имени.

```js
const fileNameList =
    Array
        .from(document.getElementsByTagName('button'))
        .map(el => el.innerText)
        .map(encodeURI)

console.log(fileNameList)
```

```html
<button><span contenteditable>name q</span>.jpeg</button>
<button><span contenteditable>name w</span>.jpeg</button>
<button><span contenteditable>name a</span>.jpeg</button>
```

- `HTMLElement.contentEditable` 
  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/contentEditable
- `Node.innerText`
  https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText